# Working with graphs

Tags: custom-list

i have a questiuon regarding graphs in SP10.

In a tasklist i have added 3 fields whcih are important for this:
- Task Status (Not started, In progress, Completed, Closed)
- Region (APAC, Americas, Europe)
- Country (depending on de Region)

I have created a list where i stated the Status's and did a count on the taskstatus from the tasklist. This works fine so i have a graph which shows the amount of status's globally

I have also created a list in which i entered the regions and a count on the regions in the tasklist which shows the amount of tasks per region (not divided by taskstatus)

The tricky part (for me) is the following.
They also want to see a graph (for example) that shows the number of status's per region so i can show them that for region Europe there are 3 tasks not started, 1 in Progress and 10 Completed for example.

I cannot manage to do this. Looks simple in excel where you can say count if this is x and that is y.

We are not allowed to work with Designer and they do not have a BI center installed. How do i get a multiple count in one list for example.

List example of possible what i wish

Region     Status        Count
Europe     Not Started   3
Europe     In progress   1
Europe     Completed     5
APAC       Not Started   3
APAC       In Progress   2
etc        etc

I also need this per country 
Region     Country       Status        Count
Europe     Netherlands   Not Started   3
Europe     Netherland    In progress   1
Europe     Netherlands   Completed     5
APAC       India         Not Started   3
APAC       India         In Progress   2
etc        etc           etc

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

I have used d3.js for this.  This gives you the ability to read the list through a caml query in javascript and generate any chart you want.  It works great.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I do have some examples if you want to pursue d3.js.